# Should I really use a single qss file for my application instead of having one for each (UI) class?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, qtstylesheets

Some posts (namely, these two: [Set CSS in QPushButton's subclass's constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32932810/set-css-in-qpushbuttons-subclasss-constructor#32933164) and [Does the use of styleSheets in a dynamic manner add a lot of computation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883301/does-the-use-of-stylesheets-in-a-dynamic-manner-add-a-lot-of-computation#1888522)) suggest that I should use a single qss file for my Qt application.

However, imagine I have a `QLabel` subclass whose purpose is (using stylesheets) to provide a particular look/behavior (say `BlinkingLabel`, however horrendous it would look). In that case, doesn't it make sense to prepare a separate stylesheet and load it in the class constructor? Wouldn't using a global file take away a very useful aspect of using OOP for UI components? Because if I do so, I can no longer just take the class and put it in another project without worrying about anything, because it can take care of itself; I have to remember to copy the relevant stylesheet entries.

Answer (score 1):

Common answer: it depends...

From my point of view, if you will split your qss to several files and implement a good logic to load them correctly - it will be better solution in compare with single file. As extra option, you still may have a global qss with basic styles.

First reason, why splitting is better: your qss will be more readable and it will me more easy to provide a support.

Second: smaller qss files, applied on different widgets works a bit faster.

P.S. If you need to reload qss on a widget (as described under your links), you need to call `polish()` + `unpolish()` instead of resetting qss text.

P.P.S. don't use stylsheets for animations. There is a [`QPropertyAnimation`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpropertyanimation.html) class. You can use it to animate color, font, etc. on your widget.

Comment: Thanks for your input :) I'm not writing a blinking label class, that would be cruel, just used it as an example. I'm leaning towards the splitting approach and I wanted to hear some thoughts as to why this could be better (like yours).