# Set CSS both in designer and in code for my custom widget

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

I have a custom widget subclassed from `QPushButton`, `MyButton`. It's implemented in a single `.cpp` file and I'm using it in Qt Creator in my application's form (I've added a `QPushButton` then promoted it to `MyButton`).

As discussed here: [Should I really use a single qss file for my application instead of having one for each (UI) class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995863/should-i-really-use-a-single-qss-file-for-my-application-instead-of-having-one-f) I wish to generally set its CSS inside its constructor (the general look of the button, the background image, hover behavior etc), but I would also like to be able to set it in Qt Creator (maybe customize the font size/color; generally specific to a particular button).

The issue is, as the `setupUi` call is issued, my buttons are created, they set their styles in their constructors, but then Qt applies the styles set in Qt Creator, immediately overriding mine.

What can I do to achieve this effect?

Comment: This doesn't seem straightforward at all. I'd try merging stylesheets in the overriden `showEvent`. But unless your stylesheets are relatively simple - it probably would be a pain - parsing CSS (or QSS) is not an easy task. Perhaps you could try simply prepending (or appending) your default stylesheet and see if it works.

Comment: @Rostislav Well, the problem is this: it's the framework that's overriding my style (in `setupUi`), so I have no control over that. If my CSS was set _after_ Qt applies the one set in Qt Creator, then that could work.

Comment: ditch Qt creator. It's a crutch.

Comment: Can we see a simple example of your code? generally calling setStyleSheet or making any style modifications after setupUi completes should have no issue. Also, don't ditch Qt Creator.

Comment: @MildWolfie Not planning to, I actually quite like it and I see no reason to not use its designer when I'm coding my UI. Anyway, well, `setupUi` is responsible for, among other things, applying the stylesheet set in Qt Creator. If I call `setStylesheet` after that, it'll overwrite any previous styles, unless I concatenate it like so: `setStyleSheet(styleSheet().append(newStyleSheet));`. However, the `setupUi` function executes after my `setStylesheet` calls, so that's of no use.

Comment: @szczurcio Do you have a special reason for setupUi to not be the first function call in your constructor? I've personally never encountered a reason for it not to be the first thing the constructor executes.